# How to create list of collections.Counter?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a for loop and each time I call a function within each iteration, and the return of that functions is from type " collections.Counter ", and I would like at the end of the loop that lst will contain all collection.Counter

```
for gram in range(0, nGram):
   lst[gram]=getCollection(gram)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a *list*, you need to use `.append()`:

```
for gram in range(nGram):
   lst.append(getCollection(gram))
```

You can turn that into a list comprehension:

```
lst = [getCollection(gram) for gram in range(nGram)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the append method of the list as others have suggested or simply use list comprehension here

```
lst = [getCollection(gram) for gram in range(nGram)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to *append* it:

```
lst.append(getCollection(gram))
```

Otherwise (if `gram` is not a valid index of the list) you will end up with an IndexError, telling you that the list does not have that many elements—yet.